# VueJs: How to correctly register vue router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to integrate Vue Router in my Vue porject.

To do this I installed the package with `npm install vue-router@4`.

In my `main.js` I integrated the router like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

// Router
import * as VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import StartNovice from './components/Novice/StartNovice';

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/novice',
    name: 'novice',
    component: StartNovice
  }
]

const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
  history: VueRouter.createWebHashHistory(),
  routes: routes,
})

Vue.use(VueRouter);

new Vue({
  router: router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Then I tried creating a link in `App.vue` like this:

```
<router-link to="/novice">Link Text</router-link>
<router-view></router-view>
```

However, I'm getting

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <router-link> - did you register the component correctly?
```

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <router-view> - did you register the component correctly?
```

Well, apparently I did not!

The [Docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/) say `Make sure to _use_ the router instance to make the whole app router-aware`. Therefore I tried changing `Vue.use(VueRouter);` to `Vue.use(router);`, but this makes things worse:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '$router')
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue router 4 is compatible with Vue 3 which has a different syntax than Vue 2 :

```js
import {createApp} from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

// Router
import * as VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import StartNovice from './components/Novice/StartNovice';

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/novice',
    name: 'novice',
    component: StartNovice
  }
]

const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
  history: VueRouter.createWebHashHistory(),
  routes: routes,
})

createApp(App).use(router).$mount('#app')
```

Make sure to install the Vue version 3

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your missing what I call the 'intercept'. Add

```
Route::get('/{vue_capture?}', function () {
    return view('index');
})->where('vue_capture', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```

To your Web.php.
Heres a working app.js. Many ways of setting it up.

```
import './bootstrap';
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";

import index from '../components/ComponentName.vue';

const routes = [
   { path: '/', component: index },
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes
})

const app = createApp({})
    .use(router)
    .mount('#app');
```

Ensure that in your index.php there is a single outermost div which has the id="app"
Then, have  where you want routed components to appear.

EX:

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="w-screen h-screen">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

keep in mind w-screen h-screen is tailwind.
Hope this helps.